# How to convert String data into date and then sort in desending order

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I have a data which consists of accessTime as a key which is actually a date in strong format i want to sort that accesstime in desending order.

```
[
0: {
accessTime: "2019-12-05 03:11:11"
id: "CBA567E1-8B8B-A88A-7A21-AD30C140502D"
name: "test proc"
type: "0"
version: "1"
},
{
accessTime: "2019-12-05 03:12:35"
id: "87DB7B7A-37C8-9BD7-D12C-D5548E402B13"
name: "testProcess88"
type: "0"
version: "1"
},
{
accessTime: "2019-12-05 03:12:48"
id: "73005C00-9FEF-762D-0FC5-D554C27B7A22"
name: "testprocess89"
type: "0"
version: "1"
}
]
```

Data is array of an object i have to sort this data on the basis of accessTime field in desending order please can some one suggest some function or so.

I have tried with this code but it is not working for me :

```
  sort(arr, key) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => (a[key].toLowerCase() > b[key].toLowerCase()) ? 1 : ((b[key].toLowerCase() > a[key].toLowerCase()) ? 0 : -1));
  }
```

please help

Comment: If that date is returned from some kind of API, I would recommend you to ask to return it in ISO string format instead, otherwise you have to assume the timezone, which is misleading. I would address this issue before actually sorting and parsing.

Comment: backend is something we cannot change now

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is almost correct, but you need to parse the dates to be able to compare them like that:

```
sort = function(arr, key) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => (new Date(b[key]) - new Date(a[key])));
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Example:

```
sort = function(arr, key) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => (new Date(b[key]) - new Date(a[key])));
}
var arr = [
{
accessTime: "2019-12-05 03:11:11",
id: "CBA567E1-8B8B-A88A-7A21-AD30C140502D",
name: "test proc",
type: "0",
version: "1"
},
{
accessTime: "2019-12-05 03:12:35",
id: "87DB7B7A-37C8-9BD7-D12C-D5548E402B13",
name: "testProcess88",
type: "0",
version: "1"
},
{
accessTime: "2019-12-05 03:12:48",
id: "73005C00-9FEF-762D-0FC5-D554C27B7A22",
name: "testprocess89",
type: "0",
version: "1"
}
]
console.log(sort(arr, "accessTime"))
```

https://jsbin.com/ditijeseva/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Glenn van Acker -  I tried but dont know still it is not working can you check

Comment: I did check, i tried it in the console, and it works fine, what's the error you get? I did have to remove the 0: from the json data, and seperate the properties with comma's.

Comment: it is not sorting the value according to time any fiddle will help thanks

Comment: can you please provide the error you are getting?

Comment: Ok Lemme post the array

Comment: I added example of what i wrote in my console, and it does in fact work.

Comment: [ {"accessTime": "2019-12-05 03:11:11", id: "CBA567E1-8B8B-A88A-7A21-AD30C140502D", version: "1", type: "0", name: "test proc"},
 {accessTime: "2019-12-05 03:12:35", id: "87DB7B7A-37C8-9BD7-D12C-D5548E402B13", version: "1", type: "0", name: "testProcess88"}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203665/discussion-between-glenn-van-acker-and-mayank-purohit).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
arr.sort((a,b)=>{
let c=new Date(a.accessTime);
  let d=new Date(b.accessTime);
  if(c>d) return -1;
  if(c<d) return 1;
  return 0;
});
```